# change position of drop down pointer?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
 <div class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to move the pointer to the drop down horizontally?
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/%60%60)

Comment: the fiddle link is broken.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/

Comment: can you show image what you actually want to do ?

Comment: can't get your point

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you will have to change the arrow, the changes are in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6ju97rd/)

```
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    left: 110%;
    top: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu:before {
    top: 0;
    left: -8px;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
}
.dropdown-menu:after {
    top: 0;
    left: -6px;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
}
```